# NoReverseMatch with slug variable, works with hard coded value

Tags: django

I'm updating some code from a Django 1.11 project to Django 2.x, and in one template (contacts list view with FK back to Clients), I am getting "NoReverseMatch" since it is not seeing the slug value in the URL parameter.  If I hard code the value it works, and the same variable displays the proper value for each record if I just display as text on the page.
I don't see why the variable is getting dropped, but probably something stupid I've done.
This works:

```
<td class="">
<a href="{% url "clients:view" slug='sony' %}">
{{ contact.client.slug  }} 
</a>
</td>
```

This gets the NoReverse Error

```
<td class="">
<a href="{% url "clients:view" slug=contact.client.slug %}">
{{ contact.client.slug  }}
</a>
</td>
```

In both cases, the variable {{ contact.client.slug  }} returns the proper data.

urls.py:

```
import ...

app_name = "clients"
urlpatterns = [
    path("ajax/validate_client_code", validate_client_code, name="validate_client_code"),
    path("", ClientListView.as_view(), name="list"),
    path("new/", ClientCreateView.as_view(), name="new"),
    path("edit/<slug:slug>/", ClientUpdateView.as_view(), name="edit"),
    path("delete/<int:pk>/", ClientDeleteView.as_view(), name="delete"),
    path("<slug:slug>/", ClientDetailView.as_view(), name="view"),
]
```

Can anyone point out my mistake? Has to be something really simple, but I just cant see it.

Comment: Is this the main urls.py file or inside an app?

Comment: Inside an app.. Main just has the include (2.x)  path("clients/", include("iqms.core.urls.client_urls", namespace="clients")),
    path("contacts/", include("iqms.core.urls.contact_urls", namespace="contacts")),

Comment: what does `client.contact.slug` return? Also, what does the slug field look like in your models.py?

Comment: client.contact.slug returns the value from the record, 'sony' in the test record - same value.  At least when I display it as text in that link or other places, it is not null. But when I try to pass it as the parameter, it seems if the same field is null.  This syntax worked fine on Django 1.11.8 where I pulled the code from an older project.